# I want to upload a image from web page ,it does not go to media directory

Tags: django

When I upload the image from admin panel it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/shop/images/Digital_India_empower_youth.jpg but when I upload from web page it shows uploaded with name in admin panel and no directory displayed and does not show in directory of project

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300,default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', default="")
    #chk=True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

## views.py

```
def product(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST.get('name','')
        category=request.POST.get('category','')
        price=request.POST.get('price','')
        desc=request.POST.get('desc','')

        image=request.POST.get('image','')
        product=Product(product_name=name,category=category,price=price,desc=desc,image=image)
        product.save()

        return render(request, 'shop/sell.html')
```

## setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

## sell.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="price">Price</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price"
name="price"placeholder="100">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="desc">Description</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc"
name="desc" placeholder="Write few things about books">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="image">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file"id="image" name="image">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sell</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: Post your settings please.

Comment: what do you want to know @Hybrid

Comment: I have posted settings @Selcuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that i was not using file storage and only name of file save in image field so use the described format which is described below

## views.py

```
if request.method=="POST" and request.FILES['imag']:
    image=request.FILES['imag']
    fs=FileSystemStorage()
    fs.save(image.name,image)
    image=image
    name=request.POST.get('name','')
    category=request.POST.get('category','')
    price=request.POST.get('price','')
    desc=request.POST.get('desc','')
    product=
    Product(product_name=name,category=category,
    price=price,desc=desc,image=image)
        product.save()
    sel=True

    #chk=True

return render(request,'shop/product.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're settings file look but you need to setup [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url) and [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-root)
There is a couple of way's you can do this, you can use Django [FileSystemStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url) or use [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and save it over model.

Django have the complete example on how to do this read the [FileUplods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads) section.

In the end for the HTML you need to set and this is mandatory `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or the `request.FILES` will be empty.

Comment: this is not my problem to upload image and save in database.I am able to upload but my problem is when i upload from admin panel it goes to media directory of my project but when i upload from web page it does not upload to media directory.and that's why i am not able to preview in my web page.The image which is in media directory it is shows in web page